# How can I check if a mail has a valid digital signature?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I need to validate if an incoming mailitem is signed in Outlook 2010.

If a mailitem is not signed, it should be moved into a "NOSIG"-folder.

While researching, I found (and sort of confirmed) that Outlook 2010 modifies the MessageClass to "IPM.Note", so I tried to use the PropertyAccessor and read the Security-Flags.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub TRCR(MAIL_ITEM As MailItem)

    Dim PR_SECURITY_FLAGS As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    'Security-Flags: 0=none, 1=encrypted, 2=signed, 3=both
    PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = MAIL_ITEM.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003")

    'Modulo because, sometimes the flags value is added to a multiple of 32... <unfortunately I lost the source>
    If (PR_SECURITY_FLAGS > 32) Then PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = PR_SECURITY_FLAGS Mod 32

    If PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = 2 Or PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = 3 Then
        'Do all that fancy stuff I want to with that signed Mail
    Else
        MAIL_ITEM.Move Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders.Item("NOSIG")
    End If

End Sub
```

I use an Outlook rule to run that script on every incoming E-Mail.

It sometimes moves signed mails to the NOSIG folder.

In those cases, the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS were both at 0, before and after that Modulo-Codeline. So being 0, the script worked right but since the mail was signed, the flag shouldn't have been 0 but 2.

I resent the same signed mail dozens of times, just to always see the same thing happening. Most of them are treated correctly while a few always appeared to show the flag 0 instead of 2 while they were signed.

I tried to pause the script for 1-5 seconds with `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)` thinking that the script may be too fast for the PropertyAccessor or something, but the pause didn't work. (I couldn't "feel" that five seconds delay while processing multiple mails.)

I start to think that it is an Outlook problem (maybe manipulating Security-Flags similar to MessageClass but not every time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` is only set on the outgoing messages to tell Outlook to encrypt the message when it is actually sent. It will not be present on the incoming messages - take a look at the messages with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

For the incoming messages, you'd think you could check the `MessageClass` property and see if it is `"IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned"`, but OOM tries real hard to represent signed and encrypted messages as the regular `IPM.Note` messages. You would have to either bypass OOM completely and use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, including VBA, I am its author). Something like the following would let you check the real message class:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set SourceMsg = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(MAIL_ITEM , true)
MsgBox SourceMsg.MessageClass
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, if `PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` is only set for outgoing mails, why could I read it on incoming Mails too? Is Outlook it setting it afterwards by itself? Most of my test-mails were treated correctly even encryption. 
Your "Redemption" looks really interesting but I think I cannot use it for my company.

Comment: PR_SECURITY_FLAGS is not a a property actually set on the message itself and exposed by the underlying store provider, it is a fake property furnished by the Outlook Object Model and only available through the PropertyAccessor and the fake IMessage object exposed by the MailItem.MAPIOBJECT property.